# rule, colorbox, space

Tags: tabularx, rules, rowcolor

I have three questions about this table:

1. The space between the  `\toprule` and the description is greater than the space between the description and the  `\midrule`. How Could I change this that both spaces are equally.
2. How can I introduce a vertical rule between  `$+$ 2-fold (20-fold)` and  `Rep. 2`
3. How can I do that the blue bare is not covering the text and that the bare is not going over the margin of the table

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % box
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95} % blue color
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}


\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\scriptsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\scriptsize\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\settowidth\colwidth{time} % set width of 1st col.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}*  {9}{C} @{}}
    \toprule 
 \textbf{Time } & \textbf{Rep. 1}& \textbf{2-fold }& \textbf{$+$ 5-fold (10-fold)} & \textbf{$+$ 2-fold (20-fold)}  & \textbf{Rep. 2}& \textbf{2-fold }& \textbf{$+$ 5-fold (10-fold)} & \textbf{$+$ 2-fold (20-fold)}\\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{5}} & 1.1 & & & & 2.1 &\\
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{lightmintbg} & 1.2& & & &  2.2 & & & &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{10}}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
\addlinespace
&1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{15}}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{20}} & 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{30}} & 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\scriptsize\textbf{45}} & 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
\addlinespace
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\endtabularx
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding request 2: Vertical lines are incompatible with horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Comment: Regarding 3: Do you additionally want to make sure, the text in the first column is vertically centered with respect the the adjacent 3 columns. Currently it is slightly shifted upwards? If you always have a short entry that you want to vertically center widht respect to three (or any odd number of rows), there is no need for `\multirow`. Just place the text in the middle row, for example as in `\rowcolor{lightmintbg} \scriptsize\textbf{5} & 1.2& & & &  2.2 & & & &\\ `

Comment: Regarding the too wide `rowcolor`, you could try `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}P{\colwidth}*  {9}{C}<{\kern-\tabcolsep}}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}*  {9}{C} @{}}`. This should also fix the spacing in the column headers, which is what I assume you referred to in request 1.

Comment: In your table, you currently declare a total of 10 columns, but you only seem to use 9 of them. Is this intentional, e.g. will you add a tenth column header later on or will you only use 9 columns?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion with `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\scriptsize\bfseries}c*{9}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}@{}}[colortbl-like]
\toprule 
\normalsize Time & \bfseries Rep. 1 & \bfseries 2-fold & \Block{}<\bfseries>{$+$ 5-fold\\ (10-fold)} & \Block{}<\bfseries>{$+$ 2-fold\\ (20-fold)}  &
\bfseries Rep. 2 & \bfseries 2-fold & \Block{}<\bfseries>{$+$ 5-fold\\ (10-fold)} & \Block{}<\bfseries>{$+$ 2-fold\\ (20-fold)}\\ 
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{5}& 1.1 & & & & 2.1 &\\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg} & 1.2& & & &  2.2 & & & &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{10}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
&1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{15}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{20}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{30}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{45}& 1.1& & & & 2.1 &\\
& 1.2& & & &  2.2 &\\
& 1.3& & & &  2.3 &\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw ([xshift=3mm]1-|6) |- ([xshift=3mm]last-|6)  ;
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above]

Comment: @ Pantigny Is there another userpackage I could use because I can not compliate it also after several rounds and could I also elongate the vertical line through the whole table?

Comment: For the vertical rule, I have changed my answer. I think that your TeX installation is not up-to-date. You should try to update it.

Comment: If you use Overleaf, you should update the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLives:`https:www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: thank you very much! exactly I use overleaf ;)

Comment: I have an additional question. When I want to expand the table with rows, what do I have to change that also the color is expanding over the whole line?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If you add new columns, you have nothing else to do: the command `\rowcolor` in the first cell will color the whole row. If you add a new row and you want it colored, you add, of course, a new command `\rowcolor`...